# Why does Google Firebase Cloud Firestore has "write", "update" security rules, while we should not allow users to write directly on database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm implementing an application that using Google Firebase Cloud Firestore. Because my application has a lot of small write requests, it will be very costly if I use Firebase Cloud Functions in the middle. Therefore, I asked a question on [Should we allow users to write to database directly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425594/should-we-allow-users-to-write-to-database-directly-how-to-do-it-correctly). All responses said that I should not do so. Then, why does Google Firebase Cloud Firestore has "write", "update" security rules? Users should not write to the database anyhow.

**EDIT** (responding to DIGI's comment & answer):
From the answer, it seems like we can use the firebase rule instead. Then, how should we correctly use them?

For example, my app is recording user's location when they turn on the map & update it to the database so that user's friends can see it in real-time. How should I ensure that the data is in the form {longtitude: double, latitude: double, timeStamp: TimeStamp}, and the user doesn't change any other few in the document?

Comment: This post could use some formatting and clarification, shift its direction from opinionated to solution-based. Would you rephrase your question so it meets Stack Overflows guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misconception from standard MySQL databases and similar where a server acts as a layer of logic and sits between the client and database.

Firebase still has this layer of logic in a simplified version known as [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) which allow basic read and write operations from the client. The design is by shifting computing power from the server backend onto the client instead, saving in server computing costs on their backend by distributing that requirement to users' devices.

The concerns listed in SE are from people who are unaware of the limitations and restrictions you can place inside rules and your project to control what can be requested with firebase and your app.

To clarify, Firebase does not hide your database keys, they are easily accessible and yes, a user can theoretically make a client using your database backend. but so long as rules are in place, conditions defined, Cors configuration, and app origin settings are enforced, you can prevent all of this.

Comment: Are there any reference or document on how to do Cors configuration, and app origin settings for Firebase?

Comment: That is a loaded question, but some can be found in the Firebase Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config -  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/xhr/ - 
https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 1):

For multiple writes, Realtime is ideal since it can handle data faster and more cost-effective than Firestore writes.
So my example will respond with the intent of realtime database per your edit.

```js
{
 “rules”: {
 “location”: {
 “$uid”: {
 “.validate”: “newData.hasChildren(['longtitude', 'latitude', 'timestamp']) &&
               newData.child('longtitude').isNumber() &&
               newData.child('latitude').isNumber() &&
               newData.child('timestamp').val() <= now”, 
 }
 }
 }
}
```

I highly suggest getting familiar with some core concepts

https://medium.com/@juliomacr/10-firebase-realtime-database-rule-templates-d4894a118a98

Full documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database